# iOS firebase database query data in specific index

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

In my database one section have 10000+ records. I just want query I specific index like the 56th ... 96th. Can I have a way to do that?

```
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let q = (ref.child("WORLDS").queryOrdered(byChild: "publishTime"))
    q.queryLimited(toLast: 40)
q.observe(.value, with: { (snap) in ...
```

Like that I just got the last 40 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `queryLimited` on a location or query, it returns a new query. So you'll need to make sure you keep a reference to that new query:

```
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

let q = (ref.child("WORLDS").queryOrdered(byChild: "publishTime"))
let q2 = q.queryLimited(toLast: 40)
q2.observe(.value, with: { (snap) in ...
```

Or just:

```
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

let query = (ref.child("WORLDS").queryOrdered(byChild: "publishTime")).queryLimited(toLast: 40)
query.observe(.value, with: { (snap) in ...
```

Comment: But how can I query a specific index? Not the last or first.

Comment: You cannot access items by index. It goes against Firebase's realtime nature. But you can use `queryStartingAtValue()` to start at a specific anchor point (typically the last item on the previous page). See my answer here for more on that (and a code snippet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691254/firebase-query-with-limit-offset-possible-solutions/27691931#27691931