# How would I set up a loop to pull records from a firebase database using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I set up a loop to pull only 10 records, then it would pull a different 10 records from a firebase database using Typescript.

I have a function that returns the first 10 however, now I want to grab the next 10

```
his.dataProvider.getProducts().subscribe((products) => {
      this.products = products;

  //Pull an Array of ASINs from Firebase Database
  this.products.forEach(product => {
  this.asins.push(product.ASIN)

  this.productKey.push(product.$key)
  //console.log(this.productKey.toString());
  var lastASIN = this.productKey.pop();
  console.log (lastASIN);

    return this.dataProvider.getNextProducts(lastASIN).subscribe((products) => {
      this.products.forEach(product => {
        this.asins.push(product.ASIN)
        this.productKey.push(product.$key)
        var newASIN = this.productKey.pop();
        console.log (newASIN);
      })
    })

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with observables, you can use `skip` and `take`.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';
```

You can use them like this:

```
this.dataProvider.getNextProducts(lastASIN).skip(numToSkip).take(10).subscribe(...
```

Just keep track of how many records you need to skip with `numToSkip` and specify how many records you want to take and you should be good.

**Edit**

Since your trying to do infinite scrolling, I would not use `skip` and `take` from rxjs.  I've not used the firebase api, but after taking a quick look at it, I would modify your firebase query to use the `startAt()` and `limitToFirst()` Firebase JS SDK functions.  There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27691931/3197720).  And the docs are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).  But the gist is this:

```
new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/widget")
   .startAt(null, lastWidgetOnPrevPage)
   .limitToFirst(LIMIT+1) // add one to limit to account for lastWidgetOnPrevPage
   .once('value', function(snap) {
      var vals = snap.val()||{};
      delete vals[lastWidgetOnPrevPage]; // delete the extraneous record
      console.log('widgets on this page', vals);
   });
```

Use `startAt()` to query for values at or beyond the value provided.  Use `limitToFirst(10)` to grab the first x number of values starting at the `startAt()` value.

Comment: I am also trying to use doInfinite(infiniteScroll, lastASIN) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {

      for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {   in order to loop it in Ionic 2. The content in the loop is basically the same above.

Comment: Great. So we are on the same page. I have added the startAt() and limitToFirst(10) to my firebase query. The problem i have is when my app loads it pulls 10 products. Then when i go to scroll down i want it to load the next 10. I can use the startAt() but i cannot figure out how to get my return from one method to go to the other method which controls the scrolling. My looping query looks like:  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {

      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

Comment: I will use a variable from the return of the first method to be used for my second method.