# How do I do a shallow query on Firebase iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to count how many object I have in my database without downloading the whole tree. I found the [`shallow`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#sts=shallow) property in the REST api. How can I use this in the iOS framework?

My code:

```
tripRef
        .queryOrderedByChild("status")
        .queryEqualToValue(TripStatus.Unconfirmed.rawValue)
        .queryLimitedToFirst(1000)
        .shallow = true //This does not work, obviously.
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) in
            result(count: Int(snapshot.childrenCount))
        }
```

Comment: That function doesn't exist.. Yet. Here's the solution [child count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FDataSnapshot class and then query for the childrenCount property.

[FDataSnapshot Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html)

[childrenCount Reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html#//api/name/childrenCount)

Comment: Nope. That only works with .value, and .value grabs everything in the node.