# Angularefire2 - query does not return expected response

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to fetch a list from firebase that has an array of email addresses. I only want the items that matches the email in the query. Here is the structure. I am trying to fetch items that match `test1@gmail.com` under `collaborators`

[image]

The query:

```
this.firebase.list('/todo', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'collaborators',
            equalTo: 'test1@gmail.com'
        }
    }).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This return empty array which is supposed to list one item!

How do I solve this..

**Solution:**

```
let results = this.firebase.list('/todo')
        .map(data => data.filter( (e) => {
            return e.collaborators.indexOf(email) > -1;
        }
    ));
    return results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the email address as if it was a value of `collaborators`. In fact, the email address is a value of one of its children.

I'd suggest restructuring your model to use the email as the key rather than the value; e.g., `test1@gmail.com: true`. I mentioned some of the advantages of this and offered a couple of links that cover the topic in my comment below.

After this minor alteration to your model, use the `map` operator to map to `collaborators` and use the `filter` operator to filter out objects whose `collaborators` object contains a property whose key matches `email`.

```
getNotesFromSpecifiedUser(email: string): Observable<any> {
    let results = this.af.database.list('/todo')
    .map(data => data.filter(data => (email in data.collaborators)))
    return results
}
```

**Important:** If there are no entries in `collaborators` an error will be thrown because the `in` keyword cannot handle null. If it's conceivable that `collaborators` will be empty, let me know.

Comment: I get this error `this.firebase.list(...).map is not a function`

Comment: You need to import the operator. `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: this returns an empty array

Comment: I made a small change that worked for me ! Accepting answer for giving the hint of using map and filter

Comment: You'll have to subscribe if you want the observable to emit anything. The `map` operator does not cause the observable to emit anything. It simply alters the potential emissions. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: I did subscribe but `email in data.collaborators` always returned empty. I have updated my question with solution

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake. The `in` keyword actually looks for a key in that matches `email`. This raises a suggestion I have about your model, though. Instead of using `0: test1@gmail.com`, consider `test1@gmail.com: true`. This makes creates a number of opportunities for you in the future, such as the ability to include the email in a path and to access the email using a [shallow query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37369483/6024090). There are a number of other [advantages to structuring your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) this way.

Comment: I would like to restructure my data. I have a question though. The solution which we worked on, does it fetch entire '/todo' and then filter locally or does it fetch only filtered data? If the solution brings the whole set of data and filter locally isn't that a potential security issue? because anybody can download the app and modify permissions locally!

Comment: What I mean by permission is the first email in collaborators is the admin of that todo item. So anybody can modify the code right?

Comment: You never want to rely on client side access restrictions. The paths to your database and its data will always be visible. You have to restrict access through rules. If there is sensitive data anywhere in your database it should be encrypted.