# How to get size of an element/list in Firebase without get it all?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to measure the size/length of an element or list in Firebase but I don't need the real content.

Something like `firebase.database().ref("users/").once("length" || "size").then(callback)`

**ps** Javascript SDK

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have a count operator, so the only way is to download all children *or* keep a separate `<children>_count` property in sync. The latter is not a trivial task (see my [answer here for one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590#37956590) and this [example Cloud Function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count)), so most often developers likely end up going with the downloads-too-much-data-but-is-trivial approach:

```
ref.child("messages").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("There are "+snapshot.numChildren()+" messages");
})
```

A more efficient way to count the children would be to fire a REST call with `shallow=true` parameter, which will give you just the keys. See [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load/34957225#34957225)

Answer (score -5):

Also found a post which does it a different way...

```
Object.keys(users).length;
```

Post: [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Why is this a bad solution?

Comment: Because the question has clear statement  : -  "but I don't need the real content", where in the users variable contains real content.