# Firebase database - Count child nodes in father nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new Firebase developer. I am develop an android app that uses firebase database.
I want to count child nodes in father node, but I don't know how to do.
[image]

Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: You'll have to download them all and call [`DataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()) or implement your own counter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all/38444523#38444523

Comment: I got it. Thank you.