# How to get number of children in Firebase Database without downloading all the node on the client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way in year 2020 to get the number of children of a node in Firebase Database without downloading the entire payload on the client? 
I have about 20 000 users in db and I want to get a count of them.

```
Users
   userUID_1
       - 300 properties
   userUID_2
        - 700 properties
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all/38444523#38444523

Answer (score 1):

**I will give you a better idea:**

**create a new node called `UsersCount`:**

```
UsersCount
|
|--------------number : "..."
```

When you save users to `Users` at the same time  update the number in the `UsersCount`, now when you want to get the users count you don't have to read the whole `Users` node, instead you just read the `UsersCount`

Comment: It is too late. The database already has thousands of users registered.

Comment: If you know how much users there are, add the node manually. And update the app to do so.

Comment: What about the client app? That's where the logic comes from. I cannot release. a hot release...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could implement a function to retrive this count within the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate. There is no count for users in the db. I don't want to download all the users every time I need the count of users. There are already thousands of users in the database.