# How to find the count of specific values from Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database consisting of a bunch of cases. I want to loop through all these cases and find the count of Male cases only, male is represented by "M".

Picture of my database.
[image: Picture of my database.]

How I am trying to query for this data:

```
databseCOVIDCases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

databseCOVIDCases.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
           if (data.child("Sex").getValue(String.class) == "M") {
               numMaleCases++;
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
});
```

When I set the text of the text view it shows 0 and then crashes with an out of memory error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through all cases and counting the ones where `Sex` is `M`, I'd recommend [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) to only read those nodes. That saves you (and your users) the bandwidth of loading all the nodes where `Sex` is not `M`.

In code that'd be:

```
Query query = databseCOVIDCases.orderByChild("Sex").equalTo("M");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       Log.i("Cases", "M case count: "+snapshot.getChildrenCount());
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { 
       throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
   }
});
```

While the above works, a few things to keep in mind:

- Any code that needs the count has to be inside the `onDataChange` method or be called from there. Other code may not run when you expect it to run.

  For more on this, see
  [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
  and
  [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)
- Reading all these nodes to only show the count it wasteful. It is much more practical (though unusual if you come from a SQL background) to store the actual count you need in the database, and update it whenever you add/remove a `M` node. While your write operations becomes more complex when you do this, your reads become much simpler, cheaper, and more scalable.

  For more on this, see [How to get size of an element/list in Firebase without get it all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all/38444523#38444523) and [Is the way the Firebase database quickstart handles counts secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590#37956590)