# Leave only NN newest entries and delete all the rest

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure.
Each user has his own data.

```
---+ root_child
   |
   +---+ Gy7FXRbRjDfAKWu7a95NgiGIZUk1  (Firebase User Id)
       |
       |
       +---+ KlNlb71qtQUXIGA4cNa (random key, generated by Firebase)
       |   |
       |   +--- timestamp = 1234567890
       |   |
       |   +--- (other data field ...)
       |
       |
       +---+ KlNlcmfMTDjxQ0BwW1K
       |   |
       |   +--- timestamp = 9876543211
       |   |
       |   +--- (other data field ...)
       |
       |
       +---+ (...)
```

Adding records occurs in this way:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("root_child");
databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .push()
    .setValue(val);
```

> [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) ... Locations generated on a single client will be sorted in
>   the order that they are created...

Now, how can I leave only 100 newest entries (for the specified user id) and delete all the rest?

Pseudocode :

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("root_child")
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .deleteLastNnRecords();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the [sort and filter functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#filtering_data).

First, I would grab the children count with a single value listener: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607203/7949696 , Or in the case of a cloud function I would count the children from the `snap` on the write trigger.

Then, if childCount > 100, I would `OrderByChild()` on your `timestamp` and then filter by `LimitToLast(childCount - 100)`

If I were you, I would use [cloud functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0) to achieve this and set a function on write to `root_child/${uid}/`

---

Edit: Source code link from comments:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children

Cheers!

---

Edit 2:  Looks like `push()` is chronologically sorted, so no need to `OrderByChild`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is what I need https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

1. AddListenerForSingleValueEvent is called only 1 time to get all the data and to delete all the old ones
2. Then we call only addChildEventListener to get only new data

   ```
       databaseReference.orderByKey()
           .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener =
                   new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                           long deleteFirst = count - Const.FB_MAX_CHILD;
                           long i = 0;

                           Log.i(TAG, "DataSnapshot children count = " + String.valueOf(count));
                           for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                               i++;
                               if (i <= deleteFirst) {
                                   // delete
                                   Log.i(TAG, "delete => " + data.getKey());
                                   data.getRef().removeValue();
                               } else {
                                   TrackData trackData = data.getValue(TrackData.class);
                                   Log.i(TAG, data.getKey() + " = " + trackData.toString());
                               }
                           }
                       }
   ```