# Flutter: How to count children in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

We have a data model designed in the Firebase for realtime questions and answers. However, we are unable to get realtime counts for a quiz.
On researching we are able to see a method addValueEventListener() which refers the DataSnaphot object with the getChildrenCount()
One of the reference links for the above info is: [android firebase - get childrens count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606235/android-firebase-get-childrens-count)

However, we are unable to find these methods in the Flutter package for Firebase. The link to the package that we are using: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database

Please advise.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed looks like the child count method is not implement in the [FlutterFire library version of DataSnapshot](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html). I'd recommend filing a feature request for it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

The fastest way to get the feature added would probably to create a PR for it yourself, but that would require you to dig into how the FlutterFire library works under the hood.

Alternatively you can listen to the [`onChildAdded` event](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onChildAdded.html), and count the children in your client-side Flutter code. It won't be significantly less efficient, since the regular SDKs also need to download all child nodes to be able to return their count.