# Get number of childs firebase android and put all the childs in a String arrayList

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

**My Child List Screenshot**

[image: My Child List Screenshot]

I need to get the number of childs (No nested childs are there!) and store it in a global public variable. Also, I want all the childs to put in a string array list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow. So what have you tried so far to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi santhosh, i have tried making a list variable outside the listener and and added every key value in for() loop, but didn't work, and for count i used the arraylist.size();

Comment: @Hafeezulhaq Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is the best way for us to see what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some form of listener. For single lookup use the valueEventListener.

Then in the OnDataChange() method that is automatically generated. Use the datasnapshot to get the childrenCount and then to loo through the children and add them to the list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
long childrenCount;
public void getListItems()
{
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            childrenCount = dataSnapshot.child("searchingUsers").getChildrenCount();
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.child("searchingUsers").getChildren())
            {
                //If you want the node value
                list.add(snap.getValue().toString());

                //If you want the key value
                list.add(snap.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    });
}
```

This makes both the variables global in the Activity. So you can reach them from anywhere in the Activity

Comment: Thank you for answer, but can you please give any idea how can use 'list' and childrenCount variable outside the Scope of Listener

Comment: You can't really. You'll have to move the code that needs the data **into** `onDataChange` or invoke it from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163512/firebase-android-count-children-and-store-it-in-a-variable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list

Comment: See in the edit. When you declare the variables outside of the function you can reach them from anywhere in the activity, not just in the listener. I'm just not sure if this is best practice

Comment: The 'list' is still empty i don't know why though i tried public List<String> itemsList() and return the list variable too, but didn't work!

Comment: Thanks for you contribution, got the solutions! by doing the task inside the scope of listener!

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all those random values, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference searchingUsersRef = rootRef.child("searchingUsers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
searchingUsersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see I have used the list only inside the callback, if you want to use the list outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Done, Thanks! But it looks like i can only tick one answer and that is the first one.

Comment: The answer from @janwilx72