# E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. in firebase android studios

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
void uploadCompImage(){
    if (compliantImageUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(type).child(victimNameid.getText().toString()+"."+getFileExtension(compliantImageUri));
        fileReference.putFile(compliantImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewCompliant.this,"UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewCompliant.this,"IMAGE UPLOAD FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String imgUrl;
                imgUrl = uri.toString();
                uploadCompData(imgUrl);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                imgSearch();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(NewCompliant.this,"IMAGE IS NOT SELECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void imgSearch(){
    StorageReference imgRef = mStorageRef.child(type).child(victimNameid.getText().toString()+"."+getFileExtension(compliantImageUri));
    imgRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            imageUrl = uri.toString();
            uploadCompData(imageUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase android count children and store it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163512/firebase-android-count-children-and-store-it-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

`fileReference.putFile(compliantImageUri)` is asynchronous the image will take some time to upload to that storage reference but `fileReference.getDownloadUrl()` will execute immediately after that line so you are immediately trying to access the download url of the image that is not uploaded yet that is why you are getting the the error ,  the image is uploaded when the

```
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewCompliant.this,"UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

is executed , so access the download url in that method or anytime after this method is returned.

**HAVE A GOOD DAY**