# Fetch data from firebase database

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have structure of database like this:

[Imgur image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paOd1.png)

In database I have lot of customers and I know how to import Customer count and single value `Assigned employee` but I need a count of all `Assigned employee`. 
For example: I have 5 customers and each have one assigned employee. I would like to receive count of employee - in this examlpe `5`

My code to import Customer count:

```
if let allServices = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Customer").value {
            if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
                self.allService.text = "0"
            } else {
                self.allService.text = (allServices as AnyObject).count.description
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to avoid downloading all children then you would have to implement and store a counter of some sorts.  This is discussed in some detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load)

Comment: Unfortunately this topic is not answer to my question...