# How to get count of childata from a parent based on child data value firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase database on my test project, what I wanted to do is something similar to how this query on mysql works.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblflashnews WHERE substr(dateCreated,1,10) = 2018-10-01
```

Is there a way to get the total count based on the child value.

```
[{
book:{
     detail:{
         dateCreated: 2018-10-01 10:10:10,
         item: bible
         }
    }
},
{
book:{
     detail:{
         dateCreated: 2018-10-01 10:10:10,
         item: bible
         }
    }
},
{
book:{
     detail:{
         dateCreated: 2018-13-01 10:10:10,
         item: bible
         }
    }
},
{
book:{
     detail:{
         dateCreated: 2018-12-01 10:10:10,
         item: bible
         }
    }
}]
```

I tried using `.numChilden()`, but it only get the total child count of a parent. But when I use it inside `forEach`, it returns an error `numChildren is not a function` so from this example only count `2` is being return since it has the same value.

```
{
  book: 2
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load

Comment: what i wanted to achieve is to get all the data from the child node dateCreated of each users...

Comment: based on your link the user id also included.. what i wanted was to get all the dateCreated of each user without using their id..then count the result

Comment: this link isnt always the exact answer for you to cut and paste, but to provide you the information to derive your solution