# Firebase Cloud Functions "Data request exceeds the maximum size " Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions on my Realtime Database. I am running a simple function to get the total users of my project but keep getting the same error:

> The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with
>   a single request

Here is my code.

```
let collectionRef = admin.database().ref('users');
    return collectionRef.once('value', function(snap) {
        console.log('users: ' + snap.numChildren());
    });
```

I estimated around 11,000 + users. Is there anyway to get the `numChildren` of a specific location in the realtime database with such a large count?

Comment: I believe each child under 'users' is too large. And would exceed the 1MB limit collectively. So I will have to find another method to count them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load)